# How to handle GCM changing the registration Id?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I was wondering how will app/device be notified if GCM server decides to refresh the registrationId which the app previously retrieved from the GCM server. 
Currently, I save the 1st retrieved registrationId and save it in the database and send this registrationId to App server. So, from next time App won't be talking to GCM server.
In this case App will never know if the registrationId is changed by GCM server. Google document suggest something to handle the case, but it does not mention what steps should be taken.
Quote from Google -

> Although the **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION** intent is typically received after a request was made by the application, *Google may periodically refresh the registration ID. So the application must be prepared to handle it at any time.*

Any suggestion will be helpful,

Thanks,
SKU

Comment: I definitely knew how to do this at one point, but googles GCM docs are down for some reason right now hah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old reg id continues to work for a while but Google send out a new one to be used in future in the canonical_id field of the response.

Comment: Do you mean the app server should get a response with new regId? Does it communicate same with device?

Comment: The app server will only communicate directly with the GCM server, which then passes on the message to the device (we hope). If you send a regid in the message and the GCM server decides to change the regid, then the new regid to use in future comes back in the canonical_id field of the response. Have a look at the dev docs when the site comes back up.

Comment: Is this still valid with [GoogleCloudMessaging API](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) ?

Comment: As far as I know, Yes. I think the new API just gives a more convenient way of registering and finding out what the regid is, so that you can store it on your server.